# How to create templates from html page automatically?

Tags: java, lucene, velocity, template-engine, text-analysis

I have a use case in which I need to render an unformatted text in the format of a given web page programmatically in Java. i.e. The text should automatically be formatted like the web page with styles, paragraphs, bullet points etc.
As I see first I will have to analyze the piece of unformatted text to find out the candidates for paragraphs, bullet points, headings etc. I intend to use Lucene analyzers/tokenizers for this task. Are there any alternatives?
The second problem is to convert the formatted web page into some kind of template (e.g. velocity template) with place holders for various entities like titles, bullet points etc.
Is there any text analysis/templating library in Java that can help me do this? Preferably open source.
Are there any other suggestions for doing this sort of task in a better way in Java?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you really need  a different template in each case, or can't you just use a single template that would act on a model object representing the text after parsing / spliting it ? (so the template would loop on pages to display them, and each page would loop on headers, paragraphs, etc...). Your real issue would be the splitting, of course.

Comment: I need the user to be able to select a web page and designate that as his template. Then all his input texts should be formatted like that web page.

Comment: Is the web page generated by your application, or is it from a different one ? In the first case, can't you just use the same template for the page that the user selects (with bogus text or Lorem Ipsum) and for the ones that you generate with the user-provided content ? In the second case, how do you expect to know which part of the page should corresponds to parts of the user-generated content ?

Comment: The web page is generated outside the application. Guessing which part of the page corresponds to which part of the content is part of the problem.

Comment: So your problem is taking "Lorem Ipsum Hello World So this guys enter into a bar" without any markup / structure ; and the URL to a random site (say "http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/news/") ; and you should be able to guess that "Lorem Ipsum" should be used as the main header, "Hello world" as the second header, and "so this guy enter into a bar" as the article content (plus you should get rid of all the ads, other contents, etc...) ? That sounds like 2 hard AI problems to me unless you have some kind of context to help ... and any template technology would do once you've solved NLP ;)

Comment: That is exactly the problem. I do not need to solve it perfectly but any good enough solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of hard parts to what you're doing.

**The user input**

If you don't ask your user to provide any context, you're never going to guess the structure of the text. At least, you should ask them to provide a title, and a series of paragraph in your GUI.

Ideally, you could ask them to follow a well-know markup language (Markdown, Textile, etc...) and use the open source parser to extract the structure.

**The external page**

If any page is used, the only things you can rely on are the "structural markup". So assuming you know the title of the page should be "Hello World", and there is a "h1" element somewhere in the page, you can maybe *assume* that this is where the header could go.

But if the pages is a div tag-soup, and only CSS is used to differentiate the rendering of the header as opposed to the bulk of the text, you're going to have to *guess* how the styling is done : that's plain impossible if you don't know how the page is made.

I don't think Lucene would help fo this (as far as I know Lucene is made to create an index of the words used in a bulk of text ; I don't think it can help you guessing which part of the text is meant to be a title, a subtitle, etc...)

**Generating templates from external page**

Assuming you have "guessed" right, you could generate the content by

- copy pasting the page
- replacing the parts to change with tags of your template language of choice
- storing the template somewhere the templating system can access it
- configure your template / view system (viewResolver for velocity) to use the right template for the rigth person

That would of course pose terrible legal questions, since your templates would incorporate works by the original website author (most probably copyrighted material)

**A more realistic solution**

I would suggest you constrain your problem to :

- using input that has some structure information available (use a GUI to enter it, use a markup language, whatever)
- using templates that *you* provide, know the structure of (and can reuse very easily)

Note that none of those points are related to the template system.

Otherwise, I'm afraid you're heading to an unreasonnable amount of work...